# Gradle sync failed: Sync failed: reason unknown

Tags: android

please how can i resolve this problem on **android studio 2021.1.1**

```
Gradle sync failed: Sync failed: reason unknown.
```

this problem started when i upgraded my android studio from **4.2** to **2021.1.1**.

Comment: There will be a log file that will show your exact problem. Please share screenshot for us to know more

Comment: can you share logcat file for showing whats  your problem?

Comment: thanks, i've gotten the solution to the problem.